# why python code for google maps api can not work suddenly

Tags: python, google-maps

the code can work before but i found it can not work recently. please saw my code as below

```
def signal_distance(lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2):
    import simplejson, urllib
    orig_coord =lat1,lng1 
    dest_coord = lat2,lng2 
    #API request
    url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins={0}&destinations={1}&mode=transit&language=zh-TW&key=AIzaSyBlwZDhGYNTrxXiQblz20v3poJTA7zTVho".format(str(orig_coord),str(dest_coord))

    result = simplejson.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
    print result
signal_distance(25.082969,121.5549714,24.9988582,121.5788795)
```

Comment: sorry,may i know why this post get -1? if i know why, i will correct the content at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the Distance Matrix API request that generates `signal_distance` function is not valid since it contains *parentheses* for `origins` and `destinations` parameters.

The specified example returns for me `NOT_FOUND` Element-level status code:

> indicates that the origin and/or destination of this pairing could not
>   be geocoded

The solution would be to replace request from:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=(<latOrig>,<lngOrig>)&destinations=(<latDest>,<lngDest>)&mode=transit&language=<lang>&key=<Key>
```

to

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=<latOrig>,<lngOrig>&destinations=<latDest>,<lngDest>&mode=transit&language=<lang>&key=<Key>
```

**Modified example**

```
def signal_distance(lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2):
    import simplejson, urllib
    orig_coord = lat1,lng1 
    dest_coord =  lat2,lng2
    orig_coord_str = ' ,'.join(map(str, orig_coord)) 
    dest_coord_str = ' ,'.join(map(str, dest_coord)) 
    #API request
    url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins={0}&destinations={1}&mode=transit&language=zh-TW&key=AIzaSyBlwZDhGYNTrxXiQblz20v3poJTA7zTVho".format(orig_coord_str,dest_coord_str)
    result = simplejson.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
    print result
```